# SSIS Project Builds in Visual Studio but not from Devenv Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have a Visual Studio Solution with one SSIS Project with a number of connection managers and packages. It builds fine in Visual Studio. It fails in our build automation system being built via the devenv command line:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" ADSMetricsETL.sln /Build Release /Project "ADSMetricsETL" 

Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.61030.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
------ Build started: Project: ADSMetricsETL, Configuration: Debug ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped =========
command exit code: 1
```

I get no errors from the build, just the "1 failed". I don't see any options on devenv to increase the verbosity. This solution used to build find in the build automation system. I made a couple of minor changes to one package and now it doesn't build at all.

Also, never noticed this before but why when the command line says "/Build Release" is it building "Configuration: Debug"?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance the minor changes involved a Script Task/Component?

Comment: Nope. Had to change one of the tables in a data flow. Four columns from varchar(50) to varchar(255). So I had to update the metadata in the data flow source/target to match the table design. Really I just opened the data flow source and target components and then saved them. VS automatically updated the column metadata. So it was a REALLY trivial change...

Answer (score 0):

One of the Connection Managers was inadvertently updated in the process. It would have been helpful if the Build gave me some indication of the error. I had to go back through the Subversion logs and inspect everything listed as changed. When I saw the Connection Manager listed I said "Huh? I didn't make changes to that Connection Manager..." I reverted the Connection Manager, committed everything and now it builds.